# Seeking one-liner sapply/map/whatever for repeated substitution

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

```
library(tidyverse)
original<-tribble(
            ~label,
            "This",  
            "Wrong",  
            "Sub",
            "Okay",
            "Nothing"
)
tr<-tribble(
            ~from,~to,
            "This", "That",
            "Wrong", "Right",
            "Sub", "Super"
)
original$label=sub("This","That",original$label)
original$label=sub("Wrong","Right",original$label)
original$label=sub("Sub","Super",original$label)
```

I want to make a bunch of substitutions on a column ... as in the last 3 lines of code.  I figure I could define a data.frame with the list of from->to pairs and "apply" it someway, but examination of various sapply ... lapply ... map etc just didn't seem to fit the bill.  I'm guessing there is a clever one-liner for this application.

Answer (score 2):

Within an `ifelse` call, use the `match` function to pick out the appropriate value from `tr$to` on the basis of the position in `tr$from` or if not present leave as the `original$label` value:

```
modified <- ifelse( original$label %in% tr$from ,  # the `test`
                    tr$to[ match(original$label,   # the consequent
                     tr$from)], original$label )   # the alternative
modified
[1] "That"    "Right"   "Super"   "Okay"    "Nothing"
```

Answer (score 2):

Ways to do this in tidyverse:

```
recode(original$label, !!!deframe(tr))
[1] "That"    "Right"   "Super"   "Okay"    "Nothing"
```

---

```
str_replace_all(original$label, deframe(tr))
[1] "That"    "Right"   "Super"   "Okay"    "Nothing"
```

---

```
coalesce(!!!rev(left_join(original, tr, c(label='from'))))
[1] "That"    "Right"   "Super"   "Okay"    "Nothing"
```

Answer (score 0):

`Reduce` can sequentially pass in `original$label` into different mapping in `df`:

```
Reduce(function(original,index) sub(tr$from[index],tr$to[index],original),seq_along(tr$from),original$label)
[1] "That"    "Right"   "Super"   "Okay"    "Nothing"
```